# How to use a queryset filter with M2M models in django admin-export?

Tags: python, django

I need to export some data in Django Admin, I'm using the `django-import-export` lib and the export is fine, the only problem is that it gets the `ID` of the attribute instead of his name(of course)

Given the models, on the Operation export, I want the `book` atribute to get all the book's `title` instead of the ID's tied with the operation

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    value = models.FloatField()



class Operation(models.Model):
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Book, through='BookOperation')
    sender = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateField()


class BookOperation(models.Model):

    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    operation = models.ForeignKey(Operation)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is the `OperationResource` in admin.py

```
class OperationResource(resources.ModelResource):
    book = fields.Field(column_name='Book(s)', widget=ManyToManyWidget(Book))
    class Meta(object):
        model = Operation
        exclude = ('id',)

    def dehydrate_book(self, operation):
        return operation.book.get()
```

With the code like this, i'm getting

> get() returned more than one Book -- it returned 2!

I tried using Operation.book.filter but doesn't see to work, i must be doing something wrong !